# Multiple Sums off Same Column

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate-functions, where-clause

I need this select query to return the sum of the same column based on different where clauses. Basically just looking for a way to merge these multiple select queries. Please see below. Any help is very much appreciated!

```
DECLARE @prEndDate  smalldatetime
SET @prEndDate='2014-01-05'

SELECT  Employee, SUM(Amount) as Deduction
FROM bPRDT
WHERE PREndDate=@prEndDate  
AND EDLCode=100 AND EDLType='D'  
GROUP BY Employee

SELECT  Employee, SUM(Amount) as DeductionPlus
FROM bPRDT
WHERE PREndDate=@prEndDate  
AND EDLCode=101 AND EDLType='D'  
GROUP BY Employee

SELECT  Employee, SUM(Amount) as Match
FROM bPRDT
WHERE PREndDate=@prEndDate  
AND EDLCode=600 AND EDLType='L'  
GROUP BY Employee

SELECT  Employee, SUM(Amount) as MatchPlus
FROM bPRDT
WHERE PREndDate=@prEndDate  
AND EDLCode=601 AND EDLType='L'  
GROUP BY Employee
```

Finally fixed. Here's what it ended up being:

```
DECLARE @prEndDate smalldatetime
SET @prEndDate ='2013-12-29'
SELECT  
REPLACE(c.SSN,'-',''),
SUM(CASE WHEN a.EDLType='D' AND a.Amount > 0 AND (a.EDLCode=100 OR a.EDLCode=101) THEN a.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Deferral,
SUM(CASE WHEN a.EDLType='L' AND a.Amount > 0 AND (a.EDLCode=600 OR a.EDLCode=601) THEN a.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS EmployerMatch,
SUM(CASE WHEN a.EDLType='D' AND a.Amount > 0 AND (a.EDLCode=100 OR a.EDLCode=101) THEN a.SubjectAmt ELSE 0 END) AS Compensation415,
SUM(CASE WHEN a.EDLType='D' AND a.Amount > 0  AND (a.EDLCode=100 OR a.EDLCode=101) THEN a.SubjectAmt ELSE 0 END) AS PlanFullYearCompensation,
SUM(CASE WHEN a.EDLType='E' AND a.Amount > 0 AND (a.EDLCode=1 OR a.EDLCode=2 OR a.EDLCode=3)  THEN a.Hours ELSE 0 END) AS PlanHours
FROM  bPRDT a  
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT SSN, Employee FROM bPREH) c ON a.Employee=c.Employee    
WHERE a.PREndDate=@prEndDate 

GROUP BY c.SSN  
ORDER BY Deferral DESC, c.SSN ASC
```

Comment: Check out [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `UNION` or `CASE WHEN` clauses.

```
SELECT  
      Employee, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN EDLCode=100 AND EDLType='D' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as Deduction,
      SUM(CASE WHEN EDLCode=101 AND EDLType='D' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as DeductionPlus
      SUM(CASE WHEN EDLCode=600 AND EDLType='L' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as Match
      SUM(CASE WHEN EDLCode=601 AND EDLType='L' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as MatchPlus
FROM  bPRDT
WHERE PREndDate=@prEndDate 
GROUP BY Employee
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly.

Comment: It seems to be ignoring by Where clause. Any idea why? I've even tried inserting the PREEndDate=@prEndDate into the CASE WHEN clause. It simply ignores it, and otherwise works as intended. Hmm..

Comment: well the declaration and set of @preenddate should be added (but I guess you did it ?).

Comment: Yes, I did do that. It is summing the entire column, not just the rows where PREndDate=@prEndDate.

Comment: Well, so it looks like it's working perfectly, no ? Also like that : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f736/15

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. I added a Join, and it works on sqlfiddle but not in SSMS. If you could take a look you would be a life saver. Thanks for everything so far. [sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ed53a/7/0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ed53a/7/0)

Comment: @user3191188 could you recreate the sqlfiddle with sql server as db ? Cause there, you did a mysql one...

Comment: Yes sir. This one illustrates the problem perfectly. [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2b1ae/3/0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2b1ae/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can move the condition out of the `WHERE` clause and in to a `CASE` statement, so you only sum the rows that interest you:

```
DECLARE @prEndDate  smalldatetime
SET @prEndDate='2014-01-05'

SELECT   Employee, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN EDLCode=100 AND EDLType='D' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) 
           AS Deduction,
         SUM(CASE WHEN EDLCode=101 AND EDLType='D' THEN amount ELSE 0 END)
           AS DeductionPlus,
         SUM(CASE WHEN EDLCode=600 AND EDLType='L' THEN amount ELSE 0 END)
           AS Match,
         SUM(CASE WHEN EDLCode=601 AND EDLType='L' THEN amount ELSE 0 END)
           AS MatchPlus
FROM     bPRDT
WHERE    PREndDate = @prEndDate  
GROUP BY Employee
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by Employee,EDLCode,EDLType instead of just Employee.